# How to disable Host name verification for nimbus JWKS ResourceRetriever

Tags: java, ssl, java-security, nimbus-jose-jwt

First I was using 'DefaultResourceRetriever' without any configuration like this :

```
new DefaultResourceRetriever(1000, 1000);
```

and then I got the following exception

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching my-jwks-url.com found.
```

To by pass certificate check I have configured the resource retriever like below;

```
TrustStrategy trustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) -> true;

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
    .loadTrustMaterial(null, trustStrategy)
    .build();

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

return new DefaultResourceRetriever(1000, 1000, 0, true, socketFactory);
```

But it doesn't changed anything.

I could set Hostname verifier to **SSLConnectionSocketFactory** like this:

`new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier())` But nimbus ResourceRetriever only accept **SSLSocketFactory** as a parameter.

Is there any way to disable Hostname verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by extending **DefaultResourceRetriever** and overriding `openConnection(URL url)` method.

If URL is HTTPS, it creates **HttpsURLConnection**. And we can set NoopHostnameVerifier to it.

Here is my solution :

```
public class NoopHostnameVerifyingResourceRetriever extends DefaultResourceRetriever {
    
      public NoopHostnameVerifyingResourceRetriever(int connectTimeout, int readTimeout) {
        super(connectTimeout, readTimeout);
      }
    
      @Override
      protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(url);
    
        if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
          ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        }
    
        return connection;
      }
}
```